# Undefined variable usando with array en eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentado pasar una variable que recibo, entonces comparando con la variable me dice que la variable no está definida:

```
Post::where('post_id', $id)
->with(['users' => function($query){
    $query->with(['user_comments' => function($q){
        $q->where('year_comment', '=', $year);
    }]);
}])->first();
```

> Undefined variable: year

Nota: la variable llega correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la respuesta de Aprendiz no es del todo correcta teniendo en cuenta que hay un doble contexto por dos funciones anónimas anidadas, por lo cual habría que utilizar `use` dos veces, en cada función:

```
Post::where('post_id', $id)
    ->with(['users' => function($query) use ($year) {
        $query->with(['user_comments' => function ($q) use ($year) {
            $q->where('year_comment', '=', $year);
        }]);
    }])->first();
```

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo + 1

Comment: ***GRACIAS***   !!!

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando una función anónima, por lo tanto deberás hacer uso de `use` para pasarla y que exista dentro del contexto de la función así:

```
Post::where('post_id', $id)
->with(['users' => function($query){
    $query->with(['user_comments' => function($q) use($year){
        $q->where('year_comment', '=', $year);
    }]);
}])->first();
```

**Estructura de la función anónima**

```
$variable = 12;

$mensaje = function() use($variable){
    echo $variable;
};

$mensaje();
```

Lo cual va a dar como resultado:

> 12

**Referencias**

- [Funciones anónimas en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php)